# Which TSDB to store time series with sampling rate

Tags: database, time-series

I've lot of series from sensors of various sampling rate (equivalent of GigaByte of datas).

I've planned to use a database to store data of each series (name, unit, sampling rate, etc...)
And a TSDB to store the actual sensor data.

I've tried InfluxDB but I don't think it is the best solution as you have to provide the value and a timestamp.

Do you have some ideas of good TSDB ?
Thank you.
F.

Comment: Try VictoriaMetrics. It is optimized for storing and processing high volumes of time series data. See https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics .

Answer (score 1):

For a TSDB that you can store it all in, and query with existing SQL, try [QuestDB](https://questdb.io/?ref=davidgsiot) It's a relatively new, but extremely high performance, TSDB.

There's a live demo (with 1.6B rows of data) that you can query at http://try.questdb.io:9000/

Comment: Thank you :), I'll check for it.